# [composition_demo.launch.py] No executable found

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run [composition_demo.launch.py](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/b0c1389ae61172788cccf4eb4e34b3b84c408a9d/composition/launch/composition_demo.launch.py) but it shows following error:

```
$ ros2 run composition composition_demo.launch.py
No executable found
```

Below are the steps showing how I prepared the workspace and the package:

```
$ source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
$ mkdir -p ~/dev_ws/src
$ cd ~/dev_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/ros2/demos.git -b foxy
$ cd demos/
$ rm -r !(composition)  # delete everything except "composition"
$ cd ~/dev_ws/
```

In this case, I have removed all packages except "composition". Below is the directory structure:

```
user@dell:~/dev_ws$ tree -a
.
└── src
    └── demos
        ├── composition
        │   ├── CHANGELOG.rst
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   ├── include
        │   │   └── composition
        │   │       ├── client_component.hpp
        │   │       ├── listener_component.hpp
        │   │       ├── node_like_listener_component.hpp
        │   │       ├── server_component.hpp
        │   │       ├── talker_component.hpp
        │   │       └── visibility_control.h
        │   ├── launch
        │   │   └── composition_demo.launch.py
        │   ├── package.xml
        │   ├── src
        │   │   ├── client_component.cpp
        │   │   ├── dlopen_composition.cpp
        │   │   ├── linktime_composition.cpp
        │   │   ├── listener_component.cpp
        │   │   ├── manual_composition.cpp
        │   │   ├── node_like_listener_component.cpp
        │   │   ├── server_component.cpp
        │   │   └── talker_component.cpp
        │   └── test
        │       ├── composition_all.regex
        │       ├── composition_pubsub.regex
        │       ├── composition_srv.regex
        │       ├── test_api_pubsub_composition.py.in
        │       ├── test_api_srv_composition_client_first.py.in
        │       ├── test_api_srv_composition.py.in
        │       ├── test_dlopen_composition.py.in
        │       ├── test_linktime_composition.py.in
        │       └── test_manual_composition.py.in
        ├── .git
        │   └── FILES REMOVED TO KEEP THE POST SHORT
        ├── .github
        │   └── ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
        └── .gitignore

26 directories, 54 files
```

Now, I complied my workspace. Because the "composition" package is shipped with ROS, so I marked it to be overridden as shown below:

```
$ cd ~/dev_ws/
$ colcon build --allow-overriding composition
$ source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
$ . install/local_setup.bash
$ ros2 run composition composition_demo.launch.py
No executable found
```

What's wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400809/%5Bcomposition_demo.launch.py%5D-no-executable-found/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2022-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to do ;

```
ros2 launch composition composition_demo.launch.py
```

You are trying to launch a file so you need to use `launch` command

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2022-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-05-18**:
Ahhh!!! Time to have a coffee break. Thanks for the answer.